# Why did they define $\hat{\theta}=\frac{\hat{z}\times\hat{r}}{\sin \theta}$ and $\hat{\theta}=\hat{\phi}\times \hat{r}?$

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

[image]

---

I am seeing this approach first time in an Electrodynamic book. They have used straightforward formula.
From the figure,  I could able to prove $$x=r\sin \theta \cos \phi,$$ $$y=r\sin \theta \sin \phi$$ and $$z=r\cos\theta$$

I can see that $\hat{r}=\frac{x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}}{r}.$ I can deduce the given expression of $\hat{r}$. But, I am not able to deduce the other two expresions. Why did they define  $\hat{\theta}=\frac{\hat{z}\times\hat{r}}{\sin \theta}$ and $\hat{\theta}=\hat{\phi}\times \hat{r}?$ How $\theta$ related to $\hat{\theta}$? How $\phi$ related to $\hat{\phi}$?

Comment: These are the unit vectors along the directions the point moves if you make an infinitesimal change in $\phi$ or $\theta$ respectively while holding the other spherical coordinates fixed. (More formally, if the point is $\vec r = x\hat x+y\hat y+z\hat z$, then $\hat\phi = \dfrac{\partial\vec r/\partial\phi}{\|\partial\vec r/\partial\phi\|}$, and similarly for $\hat\theta$.)

Comment: How $\hat{\phi}$ related to the angle $\phi$ in the figure?

Comment: $\hat\phi$ is the unit vector along the direction the point moves if you make an infinitesimal change in the angle $\phi$ while holding the other spherical coordinates $r$ and $\theta$ fixed.

Answer (score 1):

We define them as the covariant basis vectors in terms of the spherical coordinates $$q^1 = r, \qquad q^2 = \theta \qquad q^3 = \phi$$

The new basis vectors are tangential to a coordinate line. 
In other words a line where one $q^\alpha$ is hold variable and the rest of the $q^i$ is hold constant.

The new basis vectors $\vec{g_\alpha}$ are derived through
$$\left(\vec{g_\alpha}\right)^i=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial q^\alpha} \frac{1}{\|\partial \vec{x} / \partial q^\alpha \|}$$
where $x^i$ are the Cartesian coordinates in spherical coordinates.

Using this we can derive $\hat{\theta}, \hat{\phi}, \hat{r}$ which have the property that they are perpendicular to one another.

The same property or vectors can be derived by the way your book defined it.
Since the cross product of two vectors is perpendicular two those two vectors,  $\hat{\theta}$ should be clear.

Now, can you see the idea behind $\frac{\hat{z} \times \hat{r}}{\text{sin}\theta}$?

Comment: The new basis vectors are tangential to a coordinate line. I don't understand this statement. can you explain bit?

Comment: The basis vectors are the normalized tangent vectors to the coordinate lines. So like rahul said $\frac{\partial \vec{r} / \partial q^\alpha}{\|\partial \vec{r}/\partial q^\alpha\|}$. Is there an expression that is unclear?